# access scope in another template in same state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

How can I get access to $scope in another template in the same state?
In my code below I whould like to get access to a function in controller Grid from (by using) chart.html

```
        .state('demo.content', {
            url: '',
            views: {
                'chart': {
                    templateUrl: './App/chart.html',
                    controller: 'Chart'
                },
                'grid': {
                    templateUrl: './App/grid.html',
                    controller: 'Grid'
                }
        })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not wanting to call a function in another scope directly. I would recommend doing it using the $broadcast and $on mechanism where one controller broadcasts messages that another controller can subscribe to.

Here's an example:

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('controller1', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.notify = function () {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('click', 'heres the message');
    };
}]).controller('controller2', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.$on('click', function (event, data) {
        $scope.message = data;
    });
}]);
```

With a full fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6dbgo6pt/2/ .

Documentation is here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

There is such a thing as actual function binding ( the '&' binding ), but that's in a directive. Say you would have something like:

```
<div ng-controller='mycontroller'>
    <div my-button-directive clickcallback='doSomething' />
</div>
```

Then inside your `my-button-directive` you can use an '&' binding on the clickcallback attribute. That would allow you to call the `doSomething()` in the `mycontroller` scope from the directive. But like I said, I don't think that scenario applies to you.

Answer (score 0):

To get access to another scope is not good style.Especially when scope is isolated.That's why I suggest you to use AngularJs Events.